# android studio gravity center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout, inside which i have a few ImageViews (For header and footer). Then, in the space between the images, I set a ScrollView (Vertical) with a nested LinearLayout (Also vertical).

Thing is, I can't get the buttons inside the LinearLayout to center vertically (They are already centered horizontally). And yes, I have tried to use gravity = "center" to no avail. here is what it looks like:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "match_parent"
  android:layout_above = "*Image1*"
  android:layout_below = "*Image2*"
  >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    >

    <Button><Button/>
    <Button><Button/>
    <Button><Button/>
    <Button><Button/>

  <LinearLayout/>
<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: You need to provide a simple sketch how is your view look likes. Just use paint or whatever simple tools you have.

Comment: Should add something else. When using few buttons I have no problem getting them centered. It is when they get outside the boundaries of ScrollView that I'm having issues.

Comment: Ok, problem solved, all I had to do was nest the ScrollView in another LinearLayout, and from there stablish the limits and gravity. Anyway, thanks to everyone who helped me. You are great guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ScrollView needs to have a fixed height. More like it has to know the heights of all the children inside it inside it know how much it can scroll up and down. Therefore it enforces that its children have a height of wrap_content.

Coming to your case, your LinearLayout has a height of wrap_content. Now since you are trying to wrap the height of the LinearLayout to the children of the LinearLayout, the children do not have the freedom to move vertically in the LinearLayout. Hence, you cannot center vertically in a container whose height is wrap_content. Similarly, you cannot center horizontally if your width is wrap_content.

I hope this clears your doubt. :)

Comment: Yes, that helped give me sme insight, but still unable to solve my problem. My ScrollView does have a fixed height, and I want my LinearLayout centered around that area. I tried to use only layout_gravity = "center" but that makes my layout escape the boundaries of the scrollview.

Comment: This comment was the one that lead me to a solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding for question asked it can be done as follows :

in linear layout inside scroll view add these

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

example :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:text="btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn3" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

hope it helps

Comment: The issue I have with this suggestion is that my LinearLayout gets out of the ScrollView boundaries. Alas, I can't scroll to the first button (One of my views use around 22 of them), and if I scroll down I get to a large blank space.

Comment: remove layout gravity from linear layout